# Suggest to improve page load speed

Tags: php, mysql, magento, parsing

I've planned a custom product page in my Magento shop.
I'll try to explain as best as I can.

When you are in the product list page and you clic on the product that is a configurable product the system goes to set the availability of the single product of the configurable in real time.
First of all you must know that the system manages two differents types of availability that depends in what wharehouse the product is stored.
So, when you go in the configurable product the system check the availability in the first wharehouse and if is not, it goes to parse a web page that contains the availability of the product in the second wharehouse.
I've made a mysql table in the db called 'index' that contains the sku of single products and the relative url of the page to parse to get the real time availability.
Obviusly I haven't the access to the db of the second wharehouse.
Now, it works fine but as you can imaginate the load time is too long.
What's your suggest to improve my web pages?

Comment: you shouldn't call your table index, this is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql

Comment: Sorry, it's a typing error here, the table is called 'indexes'

Comment: Hi Giacomo, I am still not very clear on the second warehouse. Is it another instance of Magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see it, when multiple users will be going on your website, each time there will be a server level hit to external wharehouse page. This is going to be very much complicated and lot of dependency on the speed and execution of wharehouse's page.

Magento provides Soap API of its own. Any external soap user, if given privileges, can send us the soap request to update the product information.

You can create product attributes you want to check for availability in magento. Ask the wharehouse team to send the automated soap requests to magento whenever any availability is changed for any product.

I have been through this where there is a dependency of other party to check for product availability. Hitting their page everytime is really very much dependent and risky.

I have followed SOAP approach now and everything is peaceful. :)